# Retrive background color of pane javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a Pane,which I have styled with background color of hex value #795548,while running the program I need to get the color of the pane,how can I achieve that?.Like there is something `getFill()` for shapes in javaFX,is there anything similar to do that with panes?

Comment: I think this post will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851893/javafx-how-to-get-background-color-of-tab-button-etc

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in method that stores this as you are actually styling using css within Java. When you go to use the

```
pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #795548;");
```

You can either create another variable beforehand and then assign it the hex code or you can create your own class in which you do exactly what I just described, but the encapsulation will reduce repetition if you have to get the hex code from several panes.