# How to get Background color of tile pane in Javafx?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Problem description - In my application, I need to get back color of tile pane (or any other control), but i don't find any property/function.

I use tile pane to show color swatches, and on its click event I want its background color.

What I want: I want to get background color of control on its click event

Comment: You shall check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851893/javafx-how-to-get-background-color-of-tab-button-etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the `ActionEvent` you can do this

```
handle(ActionEvent event){//suppose we are in the handle method
   Object o = event.getSource();
   if(o instanceof Region){
       Background b = ((Region)o).getBackground();
       Paint p = b.getFills().get(0).getFill();//paint is actually your color :)
       if(p instanceof Color){
          ((Color)p) //now you have a color :)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you sir, but i solved it by creating custom control with back color property

Comment: Probabily better to get the last fill as it is the last one to be rendered (as per the documentation of javafx.scene.layout.Background "Each defined BackgroundFill is rendered in order"). So it should be `b.getFills().get(b.getFills().size() - 1).getFill()` rather than `b.getFills().get(0).getFill()`